# ClassNotFoundException: com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.WrappedClientThrowable

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I'm getting class not found exception for com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.WrappedClientThrowable while starting my application in tomcat 8.0.36.
Libraries used

```
- gwt-user-2.8
- gwt-servlet-2.7.0
- spring4gwt-0.0.1
- gwt-log-3.1.2
```

This class is present in gwt-log but in package com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.shared. My application code is referring to the correct package but still I'm getting this exception:

```
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/allen_sauer/gwt/log/client/WrappedClientThrowable
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5202)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.WrappedClientThrowable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 24 more
```

Not sure which library is referring to the old package. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you `clean` `build` your project?

Comment: I did. Built it with gradle using clean option, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a gwt-user and gwt-servlet in different versions.

It would be great if you could post your full "mvn dependency:tree" (or gradle equivalent)

> EDIT:

Feels like you are using a somewhat outdated logging library.

https://github.com/fredsa/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted

Try adding this guy to your dependencies: `compile 'com.allen-sauer.gwt.log:gwt-log:3.3.2`

Comment: My gradle dependency tree is too huge to post here. However, I could see some logging methods were added to the compiled RemoteLoggerServlet class: 

`public void debug(String message, com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.WrappedClientThrowable ex) {}`

Not sure how GWT is adding these methods

Comment: I tried to add the latest `gwt-log` dependency, but that doesn't work because in application code, our custom `RemoteLoggerServlet` extends `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet` and implements `com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.RemoteLoggerService` and overrides the init method. init method is marked as final in latest version of `gwt-log.

Comment: Below are the modules it inherits: `<inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd'/>
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>
 <inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
 <inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-DEBUG" /> 
 <inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-RemoteLogger" />`

Comment: Modules are not relevant, seems like the issue is on the server side of the deal. Maybe you can simply move the logic in the offending init method to a constructror and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this issue was introduced due to some duplicate compiled classes. I got the application from a different team who have recently converted it to gradle build. When I checked the project structure and gradle scripts, I found many inconsistencies. Basically project was not converted correctly.

After I converted it correctly, this error was gone.

Thanks for the insights,  really appreciate it